# Craco interprets custom scss style file extensions also as less

Tags: create-react-app, antd, craco

I have a CRA project customized with Craco via a cracorc.js file like below.

```
const path = require('path');

const { reduce, type, toPairs, map, lensPath, over, curry, dissocPath } = require('ramda');

const isObjectOrArray = (inQuestion) => type(inQuestion) === 'Array' || type(inQuestion) === 'Object';

const getPaths = curry((predicate, parentValue, parentPath = []) =>
  reduce(
    (paths, [key, value]) => {
      if (value) {
        const asCorrectType = isNaN(key) ? key : Number(key);
        const currentPath = [...parentPath, asCorrectType];
        return predicate(value)
          ? [...paths, currentPath]
          : isObjectOrArray(value)
          ? [...paths, ...getPaths(predicate, value, currentPath)]
          : paths;
      }
      return paths;
    },
    [],
    toPairs(parentValue),
  ),
);

const edit = curry((transform, paths, config) =>
  reduce((configStage, lens) => over(lens, (c) => transform(c), configStage), config, map(lensPath, paths)),
);

const remove = curry((paths, config) => reduce((configStage, path) => dissocPath(path, configStage), config, paths));

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
      webpackConfig.output.libraryTarget = 'amd';
      webpackConfig.output.filename = 'static/js/bundle.js';
      webpackConfig.resolve.extensions.push('.less');

      webpackConfig.entry = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js');

      webpackConfig = addLoaders()(webpackConfig);

      webpackConfig.optimization.splitChunks = {
        cacheGroups: {
          default: false,
        },
      };
      webpackConfig.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;

      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
  devServer: (devServerConfig, { env, paths, proxy, allowedHost }) => {
    devServerConfig.headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization',
    };
    return devServerConfig;
  },
  babel: {
    plugins: [
      [
        'import',
        {
          libraryName: 'antd',
          style: true,
        },
      ],
    ],
    loaderOptions: (babelLoaderOptions, { env, paths }) => {
      return babelLoaderOptions;
    },
  },
};

const addLoaders =
  (loaderOptions = {}) =>
  (webpackConfig) => {
    const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'dev' : 'prod';

    const shouldUseSourceMap = mode === 'prod' && process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
    const lessRegex = /\.less$/;
    const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
    const lessModuleRegex = /\.module\.less$/;
    const localIdentName = loaderOptions.localIdentName || '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]';

    const loadersMatcher = (inQuestion) =>
      Array.isArray(inQuestion.rules) && inQuestion.rules.find((rule) => Array.isArray(rule.oneOf));
    const sassMatcher = (inQuestion) => inQuestion.test && inQuestion.test.toString() === sassRegex.toString();

    const getStyleLoader = (cssOptions, styleLoaderOptions = {}) => [
      {
        loader: 'style-loader',
        options: styleLoaderOptions,
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            plugins: () => [
              require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
              require('postcss-preset-env')({
                autoprefixer: {
                  flexbox: 'no-2009',
                },
                stage: 3,
              }),
            ],
          },
          sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'less-loader',
        options: {
          javascriptEnabled: true,
          sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
        },
      },
    ];

    const getSassLoader = (cssOptions) => {
      const styleLoaderOptions = { injectType: 'lazyStyleTag' };
      return getStyleLoader(cssOptions, styleLoaderOptions);
    };

    const getLessLoader = (cssOptions) => {
      //Insert option adds antd styles to the top of <head> tag
      const styleLoaderOptions = {
        insert: function insertAtTop(element) {
          var parent = document.querySelector('head');
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
          var lastInsertedElement = window._lastElementInsertedByStyleLoader;

          if (!lastInsertedElement) {
            parent.insertBefore(element, parent.firstChild);
          } else if (lastInsertedElement.nextSibling) {
            parent.insertBefore(element, lastInsertedElement.nextSibling);
          } else {
            parent.appendChild(element);
          }

          // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
          window._lastElementInsertedByStyleLoader = element;
        },
      };

      return [...getStyleLoader(cssOptions, styleLoaderOptions)];
    };

    const transform = (match) => ({
      ...match,
      rules: [
        ...match.rules.filter((rule) => !Array.isArray(rule.oneOf)),
        {
          oneOf: [
            {
              test: lessRegex,
              exclude: lessModuleRegex,
              use: getLessLoader({
                importLoaders: 2,
              }),
              sideEffects: mode === 'prod',
            },
            {
              test: lessModuleRegex,
              use: getLessLoader({
                importLoaders: 2,
                modules: {
                  mode: 'local',
                  localIdentName: localIdentName,
                },
              }),
            },
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
              use: getSassLoader({ importLoaders: 1 }),
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            ...match.rules.find((rule) => Array.isArray(rule.oneOf)).oneOf,
          ],
        },
      ],
    });

    webpackConfig = remove(getPaths(sassMatcher, webpackConfig), webpackConfig);

    webpackConfig = edit(transform, getPaths(loadersMatcher, webpackConfig), webpackConfig);

    return webpackConfig;
  };
```

In my `App.js` I import styles as below.

`import styles from './styles/App.scss';`

and `App.scss` file contains all styles for my custom components like below.

```
@import 'apps/help/_help';
```

and `_help.scss` is the scss file name.

However, when I run `craco start`, it fails to identify `.scss` file extension and gives below error.

`@import 'apps/help/_help'; ^ Can't resolve './apps/help/_help.less' in 'C:\Projects\my-app\src\styles'`

I'm using

```
"antd": "^4.21.5",
"@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
"craco-less": "^2.0.0",
"less": "^4.1.3",
"less-loader": "^4.0.6",
"babel-plugin-import": "^1.12.0",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
```

Can someone help find out what is the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the answer. I removed `less-loader` from the `getStyleLoader` method. This was invoked by both `getSassLoader` and `getLessLoader` methods.

And I added this loader only for the `getLessLoader` method as an extension of the loaders receieved via `getStyleLoader`.

```
  const getLessLoader = (cssOptions) => {
  //Insert option adds antd styles to the top of <head> tag
  const styleLoaderOptions = {
    insert: function insertAtTop(element) {
      var parent = document.querySelector('head');
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
      var lastInsertedElement = window._lastElementInsertedByStyleLoader;

      if (!lastInsertedElement) {
        parent.insertBefore(element, parent.firstChild);
      } else if (lastInsertedElement.nextSibling) {
        parent.insertBefore(element, lastInsertedElement.nextSibling);
      } else {
        parent.appendChild(element);
      }

      // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
      window._lastElementInsertedByStyleLoader = element;
    },
  };

  return [
    ...getStyleLoader(cssOptions, styleLoaderOptions),
    {
      loader: 'less-loader',
      options: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
      },
    },
  ];
};
```